# How to know if widget accepts only numeric characters

Tags: c++, qt

I'm coding a class derived from QInputContext. The main idea is to show an alfanumeric virtual keyboard for widgets like QLineEdit, or a numeric one if widget only accepts numbers like QSpinBox. I could check type of widget to know which keyboard use. But, Is there any "generic" way to check it? I was looking for a property or method of QWidget to check it but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`inputMethodHints`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#inputMethodHints-prop) property on the widget; for example, a `QSpinBox` sets its `inputMethodHints` to `Qt::ImhDigitsOnly` (`0x10000`) indicating that only digits are allowed.